# NGINX support changing foldername

Tags: nginx

```
    location ~ \.(jpg|png|css|js|html|json|svg|jpeg) {
            try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/amk(.*) {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/amk/app.php;
    }

    location ~ ^/ewan(.*) {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/ewan/app.php;
    }
```

Basically, I want to have this nginx config hold, but the directory will change
So it could be amk, it could be mcaq
So I want https://example.com/apps/FOLDER to redirect php to $document_root/FOLDER/app.php
But https://example.com/apps/FOLDER/images/test.jpg to go to $document_root/FOLDER/images/test.jpg
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
    location ~ \.(jpg|png|css|js|html|json|svg|jpeg) {
        rewrite ^/apps(/.*)$ $1 break;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/apps/([^/]+)/?(.*?)$ {

        set $site $1;
        set $loc $2;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$site/app.php;
    }
```

This is the solution I have found.